# Remove from a HashSet failing after iterating over it

Tags: java, collections, hash, iterator, hashset

I'm writing an agglomerative clustering algorithm in java and having trouble with a remove operation. It seems to always fail when the number of clusters reaches half the initial number.

In the sample code below, `clusters` is a `Collection<Collection<Integer>>`.

```
      while(clusters.size() > K){
           // determine smallest distance between clusters
           Collection<Integer> minclust1 = null;
           Collection<Integer> minclust2 = null;
           double mindist = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

           for(Collection<Integer> cluster1 : clusters){
                for(Collection<Integer> cluster2 : clusters){
                     if( cluster1 != cluster2 && getDistance(cluster1, cluster2) < mindist){
                          minclust1 = cluster1;
                          minclust2 = cluster2;
                          mindist = getDistance(cluster1, cluster2);
                     }
                }
           }

           // merge the two clusters
           minclust1.addAll(minclust2);
           clusters.remove(minclust2);
      }
```

After a few runs through the loop, `clusters.remove(minclust2)` eventually returns false, but I don't understand why.

I tested this code by first creating 10 clusters, each with one integer from 1 to 10. Distances are random numbers between 0 and 1. Here's the output after adding a few println statements. After the number of clusters, I print out the actual clusters, the merge operation, and the result of clusters.remove(minclust2).

```
Clustering: 10 clusters
[[3], [1], [10], [5], [9], [7], [2], [4], [6], [8]]
[5] <- [6]
true
Clustering: 9 clusters
[[3], [1], [10], [5, 6], [9], [7], [2], [4], [8]]
[7] <- [8]
true
Clustering: 8 clusters
[[3], [1], [10], [5, 6], [9], [7, 8], [2], [4]]
[10] <- [9]
true
Clustering: 7 clusters
[[3], [1], [10, 9], [5, 6], [7, 8], [2], [4]]
[5, 6] <- [4]
true
Clustering: 6 clusters
[[3], [1], [10, 9], [5, 6, 4], [7, 8], [2]]
[3] <- [2]
true
Clustering: 5 clusters
[[3, 2], [1], [10, 9], [5, 6, 4], [7, 8]]
[10, 9] <- [5, 6, 4]
false
Clustering: 5 clusters
[[3, 2], [1], [10, 9, 5, 6, 4], [5, 6, 4], [7, 8]]
[10, 9, 5, 6, 4] <- [5, 6, 4]
false
Clustering: 5 clusters
[[3, 2], [1], [10, 9, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4], [5, 6, 4], [7, 8]]
[10, 9, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4] <- [5, 6, 4]
false
```

The the [10, 9, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, ...] set just grows infinitely from there.

**Edit: to clarify, I'm using a `HashSet<Integer>` for each cluster in clusters (a `HashSet<HashSet<Integer>>)`.**

Comment: [10, 9, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, ...]  clearly is not a set. Is it a list?

Comment: Yeah, good point. A HashSet should not be able to contain duplicate objects.  Something is weird here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah. When you alter a value that is already in a `Set` (or a `Map` key), then it is not necessarily in the right position and hash codes will be cached. You need to remove it, alter it and then re-insert it.

Comment: Yes, you got it! The solution is to create a new cluster, add all the elements from minclust1 and minclust2, remove minclust1 and minclust2 from clusters, and add the new cluster. It looks like it's a bad idea to alter objects in a HashSet.

Comment: Excellent. Immutability rocks. Technically you could alter an element is a HashSet so long as you don't upset its equals and hashCode, but those should depend upon either all or none of the data. If you had HashSet<java.awt.Component> you could alter the components without fear.

Answer (score 1):

In the test shown, the `remove` fails the first time you try to remove a Collection containing more than one Integer.  Is this always the case?

What is the concrete type of the Collection used?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. It does always fail the first time I try to remove a collection with more than one integer. I use a HashSet<Integer> for each cluster in clusters (HashSet<HashSet<Integer>>).

Comment: That's odd. If you are using HashSet, why are you getting multiple values in the set.

Comment: As I said above, a HashSet should not be able to contain duplicate objects.  I think there is a deeper problem here.

Comment: And apparently retaining order.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem there is that `clusters.remove` is probably using `equals` to find the element to remove. Unfortunately `equals` on collections generally compares whether the elements are the same, rather than if it is the same collection (I believe C# makes a better choice in this regard).

AN easy fix is to create `clusters` as `Collections.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashMap<Collection<Integer>, Boolean>())` (I think).

Comment: Good point about equals, but even if it were using equals, why would the remove fail?